# "Pode" ou "podem" existir mais de um?

Tags: número-gramatical, concordância

Qual das formas abaixo é a correta?

1. Nessa caixa **pode** existir mais de um aparelho com defeito.
2. Nessa caixa **podem** existir mais de um aparelho com defeito.

Se usássemos "vários" no lugar de "mais de um", creio que tudo deveria ser colocado no plural:

3. Nessa caixa **podem** existir **vários aparelhos** com defeito.

Porém, não tenho certeza da forma correta quando usamos "mais de um". Me parece que as duas formas aparecem com frequência nos resultados de pesquisas, inclusive em livros. Ambas estão corretas?

Answer (score 4):

A linguagem não é matemática nem lógica. Uma coisa é sempre **gramaticalmente** singular, mesmo quando modificada por dizer mais de uma coisa:

1. Mais de uma pessoa está aqui.

Da mesma forma, duas coisas são sempre **gramaticalmente** plurais, mesmo quando modificadas por dizer menos de duas coisas.

2. Menos de duas pessoas estão aqui:

Comment: Menos de duas, seria só uma.